# Does Not Contain Definition for GroupBy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, func

```
public struct CardGrouping
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public List<CardGrouping> GetCardGrouping(IQueryable<Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation> queryable, Expression<Func<Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation, string>> groupingFunction)
    {
        return queryable.GroupBy(groupingFunction)
                .Where(x => x.Key != null)
                .Select(x => new CardGrouping
                {
                    Name = x.Key,
                    Count = x.Sum(groupingFunction)
                }).ToList();
    }
```

I'm trying to do something like this but getting an Error

> `IQueryable<FPSinformation>` does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy'
>   and the best extension method overload
>   `ParallelEnumerable.GroupBy<string, int>(ParallelQuery<string>,
>   Func<string, int>)` requires a receiver of type `ParallelQuery<string>`

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
var data1 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type1)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    CardType_Name = x.Key,
                    CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count1)
                }).ToList();
```

This is the actual code which I'm trying to optimise

Comment: @Neel its already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change string to Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation in fun

```
public List<CardGrouping> GetCardGrouping(List<Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation> queryable,
        Expression<Func<Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation, string>> groupingFunction,
        Func<Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation, int> sumFunction)

    {


        if (queryable.AsQueryable() != null)
        {

            var data = queryable.AsQueryable().GroupBy(groupingFunction).Where(x => x.Key != null).Select(x => new CardGrouping
            {
                Name = x.Key == null ? "" : x.Key.ToString(),
                Count = x.Sum(sumFunction)
            }).ToList();
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: tried that too in that case 
`.Where(x => x.Key != null)`
getting error as cannot convert int to string

Comment: key cannot get null every time

Comment: you can change int to int?

Comment: changed check but then how can I get the sum then?

Comment: OK change int? to int and change you condition .Where(x => x.Key != null)
to .Where(x => x.Key !=0)

Comment: but in that case how will I get the name?

Comment: you can't use Func<Areas.RetailShop.Models.FPSinformation, int> groupingFunction

to group and Sum 
because group by name and sum by another field is integer

Comment: what should i do to get my desired thing?

Comment: sorry didnt understood let chat in discussion group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98080/discussion-between-arijit-mukherjee-and-ahmed-galal).

Comment: Thanks For Such Suport and Solutoin

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with this code.

First, to make it compile, the `groupingFunction` should be a `Func<FPSinformation, int>` - the type of input is not `string`, it's `FPSinformation`.

This change will make it compile, but the compiler will choose the `Enumerable.GroupBy` extension method. The `Queryable.GroupBy` requires an `Expression<Func>` parameter, not a `Func` - so it should be `Expression<Func<FPSinformation, int>>`

```
public List<CardGrouping> GetCardGrouping(IQueryable<FPSinformation> queryable, 
                             Expression<Func<FPSinformation, int>> groupingFunction)
```

You're grouping it by an `int`, so the `.Where(x => x.Key != null)` doesn't make sense - `x.Key` cannot be null.

Comment: My mistake, I want to group by string which I changed but want to sum its count

Comment: `var data1 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type1)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        CardType_Name = x.Key,
                        CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count1)
                    })`

this is my actual code which I was trying to optimise